# A problem probably related to Lebesgue Number Lemma

Tags: general-topology

[image]
This is an exam question that i am having trouble with. I tried to show that $f$ is a closed map, but without the assumption of surjectivity i could not prove my claim of closedness. 
Also i wanted to use the Lebesgue Number lemma to get the $\delta >0$ in an open cover of $Y$, but this lemma only hold for a compact metric space.
How can i approach the problem? Any hint(s) will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $C$ is a closed subset of $X$. Then $C$ is compact, and $f$ is continuous, so $f[C]$ is compact. Finally, $Y$ is Hausdorff (since it’s metric), so compact subsets of $Y$ are closed, and $f[C]$ is therefore closed. Thus, $f$ is a closed map.

Note that you can replace $Y$ by $f[X]$, which is a compact metric space.

Comment: In the last line of your answer, you mean that we do not require surjectivity of $f$?

Comment: @User101: That’s right: no part of my argument requires surjectivity of $f$.

Comment: I strongly disagree with helping a student with an exam problem. Surely, the professor who assigned it wanted the student to solve it, not ask the internet for a solution.

Comment: @DavidWhite: **User101** did not in fact ask for a solution, and I did not give one; I merely gave a nudge in the direction(s) already being pursued, something that I did many times with my own students over nearly four decades of teaching. (I would have taken an entirely different approach to the problem.)